# How to compare 2 lists using Stream and get element form compare list?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
//FullName(String name, String fullName)
List<FullName> fullNameList = Arrays.asList(
            new FullName("Alpha", "Alpha Maz"),
            new FullName("Beta", "Beta Sew"),
            new FullName("Delta", "Delta Non"),
            new FullName("Indigo", "Indigo Loe")
            );

List<String> nameList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Delta","Alpha"});
```

Lets take the example list above.
I would like to compare nameList with fullNameList, and return the full name if any match found.

I have to use nameList as primary as I want the result to be following the sequence in nameList, I have no idea on how to "collect" the element from the compare list (fullNameList)

```
String result= nameList.stream()
            .filter(v -> fullNameList.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.getName().equals(v)))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

Actual Result : "Delta,Alpha"
Expected Result : "Delta Non,Alpha Maz"
```

Any idea how to do it with Java 8 Stream ?

Comment: Clarification - If a first name from the namesList matches a name in the fullName list, you want to extract the full into another list ?

Comment: yes, that's the result I want.

Comment: If the order of the output doesn't matter, you can store names as a `Set` and then while iterating through the `fullNameList`, filter relevant names and map to perform a join further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> nameMapper = fullNameList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(FullName::getFirstName, FullName::getFullName));

List<String> filteredList = nameList.stream()
                            .filter(nameMapper::containsKey)
                            .map(nameMapper::get)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println("nameList = " + nameList);
System.out.println("filteredList = " + filteredList);
```

*nameList = [Indigo, Alpha, Delta]
filteredList = [Indigo Loe, Alpha Maz, Delta Non]*

*nameList = [Delta, Alpha]
filteredList = [Delta Non, Alpha Maz]*

Though there is an overhead of creating a Map, in case of a realtime app, if the list is huge in number, then iteration cost will be less since fetching is O(1) since String in itself will less likely create hash collision. In the case of that too your fetching is O(log n).

In case of a smaller list, I think Eran's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: As per my understanding, there is no reason this could be costly for an in-memory list already processed as compared to processing the `fullNameList` multiple times for each `name` in the `nameList`. Just that you can modify this to use `Collectors.joining` to match the requirements of OP.

Comment: Yes, you can change the reduction according to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `map` instead of `filter` in order to map a short name to the corresponding full name.

```
String result= 
    nameList.stream()
            .map(v -> fullNameList.stream()
                                  .filter(s -> s.getName().equals(v))
                                  .findFirst()
                                  .map(FullName::getFullName))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

This is assuming `FullName` class has a `getFullName()` method that returns the data you wish to collect.

Answer (score 0):

With a small change in your code, you can get your expected output.

```
String res = fullNameList.stream().filter(f -> nameList.stream().anyMatch(n -> n.equals(f.getName()))).map(f -> f.getfullName()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Output: Alpha Maz,Delta Non

Comment: `I have to use nameList as primary as I want the result to be following the sequence in nameList`

Answer (score 0):

If you restricted to `nameList` as primary, then you can use the following:

```
String result = nameList.stream()
                .flatMap(name -> fullNameList.stream()
                        .filter(fullName -> fullName.getName().equals(name))
                        .map(FullName::getFullName)
                )
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```